# Inverse Laplace transform of a particular function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I have the following expression:
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx}dx=\frac{1}{(K^M-e^{-sM})^{\frac{a}{M}}}$$
where $a$, $M$ and $K$ are positive constants. Is it possible to find the expression for $f(x)$ through the inverse Laplace transform?
I tried but I got lost with the computations.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The Bromwich integral diverges, so we shouldn't expect the inverse transform to exist as an ordinary function. Expanding $F(s) = (b - e^{-s})^p$ into series (convergent for $\operatorname {Re} s > -\ln b$) gives an impulse train:
$$\mathcal L^{-1}[F](x) =
\sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k \binom p k b^{p - k} \delta(x - k).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I haven't understood your comment. If I expand $F(s)=(b-e^{-s})^p$ I get $\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k} b^{p-k}e^{-sk}$ but I don't understand how this is related with the Bromwhich integral and with the delta function that you wrote.

Comment: We have $p < 0$, so the binomial expansion is $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty (-1)^k \binom p k b^{p - k} e^{-k s}$. It can be shown that the LT of the distribution $\sum_k c_k \delta(x - k)$ can be evaluated termwise, so it remains to find $\mathcal L[x \mapsto \delta(x - k)](s)$. Regarding the Bromwich integral, consider the real part of $e^s/(1 - e^{-s})$ on $\operatorname {Re} s = \ln 2$. It doesn't prove that $\operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_{\gamma - i \infty}^{\gamma + i \infty} F(s) e^{x s} ds$ doesn't exist but makes it clearer why we shouldn't expect it to exist.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I do the $\Bin{p}{k}$ when $k>p$?